# Adjacency List in TypeORM not working properly

Tags: typescript, database, postgresql, nestjs, typeorm

I have been trying to create an [Entity](https://typeorm.io/entities) in [TypeORM](https://typeorm.io) having an adjacency list as shown in [this example](https://typeorm.io/tree-entities#adjacency-list).

Here is the code that I have written which is similar to the link above,

```
import {
  Entity,
  PrimaryGeneratedColumn,
  ManyToOne,
  OneToMany,
  Unique,
} from "typeorm";

@Entity()
export class Collection {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  collectionId: number;

  @OneToMany((type) => Collection, (collection) => collection.parent)
  children: Collection[];

  @ManyToOne((type) => Collection, (collection) => collection.children, {
    onDelete: "CASCADE",
  })
  parent: Collection;
}
```

However, when I try to describe the table using the `information_schema` in the database, I am unable to see the `children` entity. All I can see are the `collectionId` and `parent` columns,

| table_name | column_name | data_type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| collection | collectionId | integer |
| collection | parentCollectionId | integer |

I have been following the example given in the docs, but I am unable to understand why this is happening. If any more information is required, please let me know and I'll add it in the question.

> Version information - 
>  NestJS - Version 9.0.0
> PostgreSQL - PostgreSQL 14.4
>  TypeScript - Version
> 4.3.5
>  @nestjs/typeorm - Version 9.0.0
>  typeorm - Version 0.3.7